# What is the probability that two numbers are relatively prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The basic question that I have is in the title, but let us make it more rigorous below.

Let $N=\{1, 2, ..., n\}$, and put the (normalized) counting measure, $\mu_n$, on $N\times N$.

Let $\mathcal{S}_n= \{ (a, b)\in N\times N: gcd(a, b)=1\}$

and $x_n=\mu_n(\mathcal{S}_n).$

Then what is the assymptotic behavior of $x_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/lattice-points-visible-from-the-origin/

Comment: Answer on MathWorld, equation (1): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html

Comment: This is pretty marginal, level-wise.

Comment: A good question, but not a question of any research interest, as the answer can be found in entry-level Number Theory textbooks - and this website is for questions of research interest. 

Comment: I agree with @Gerry: it is beyond the margin.

Comment: The margin is too small to contain it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The probability tends to $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ as was mentioned by Qiaochu. This actually generalizes to arbitrary number fields, and is a less commonly known fact.

In fact in any number field, the probability that two ideals are relatively prime is given by $1/\zeta_K(2)$, where $\zeta_K$ is the [Dedekind zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) of the number field $K$. And is proven in a similar way to the classical result. Here is a reference: ["The probability of relative primality of Gaussian integers"](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-51084-2_23). For example the analogous probability for Gaussian integers is $6/(\pi^2G)$ where $G=1-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\cdots$ is the [Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_constant).

Comment: A reference for the general "less commonly known fact" is
Schanuel, S.H.: Heights in number fields, *Bull. Soc.
Math. France* **107** (1979), 433–449.  It is true also using field elements in place of ideals.  A function-field analogue was announced by Serre in *Lectures on the Mordell-Weil Theorem* (F. Vieweg & Sohn, Braunschweig 1989) and proved independently but in the same way by S.DiPippo (*Spaces of Rational Functions on Curves
Over Finite Fields*, Ph.D. Thesis, Harvard, 1990) and D.Wan (Heights and Zeta Functions in Function Fields, in *The Arithmetic of Function Fields* (1992)...


Comment: ...... likewise $1/\zeta_K(n)$ is the probability that $n>1$ ideals or 
field elements have no common factor.  This also lets you asymptotically
count rational points up to a given height in projective space over $K$.
Here's why I had to look up these references some years ago:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0104115v1.pdf


Answer (score 14):

This is a very standard counting problem in analytic number theory.
Here's a rigorous proof:
It is enough to derive an asymptotic formula for 
$$\sum_{a,b\leq n,  (a,b)=1} 1 $$
This is 
$$\sum_{a,b\leq n, d|a, d|b} \mu(d) $$
$$=\sum_{d\leq n} \mu(d)\sum_{k\leq n/d , l\leq n/d} 1$$
$$=\sum_{d\leq n} \mu(d) ((n/d)^2 + O(n/d) ) $$
$$=n^2\sum_{d\leq n} \mu(d)/d^2 + O(n\log n)$$
$$=n^2\sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \mu(d)/d^2 + O(n) + O(n\log n)$$.
$$=n^2 6/\pi^2 + O(n\log n).$$

Answer (score 9):

The probability is $\frac{6}{\pi^2} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$. A sketch of a proof can be found in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/zeta-functions-statistical-mechanics-and-haar-measure/) (actually I only show, more or less, that if the density exists it must be $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$).