# Estimate for products of integers that are relatively prime with $N$

Tags: prime-numbers, reference-request

Let $N$ be a positive integer. Are there known estimates for the product of all numbers that are smaller than $N$ and relatively prime with $N$? One can assume that $N$ is free of squares, if this helps.

Comment: Maybe http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97041/what-is-the-probability-that-two-numbers-are-relatively-prime is relevant.

Comment: As a rough guide (n!)^(phi(n)/n).  One can use an inclusion exclusion type formula to get more exact.  Also, for n prime one has the exact formula (n-1)! .  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.18

Comment: It may be that the rough guide needs to be divvided by e^phi(n) to make  it less rough.  Gerhard "Maybe Stirling's Approach Would Work" Paseman, 2012.05.18

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has thought to look this up at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, where it is http://oeis.org/A001783. There you will find the formula given in the answers here, with a reference to Apostol's textbook on Analytic Number Theory. I don't think anything there deals in asymptotics. 

Comment: Many thanks for the formula. I am trying to understand what one can get concerning the asymptotics. Any help is still appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, here is a proof of Gjergji's formula, which is a cute exercise in elementary number theory.

The idea is the same as in one of the proofs of the identity $\displaystyle n = \sum_{d | n} \varphi(d),$ only this time we will be multiplying in two ways rather than counting in two ways.

Consider the fractions $\dfrac 1N, \dfrac 2N, \ldots, \dfrac {N-1}N, \dfrac NN.$ Put them in reduced form, that is $\dfrac ad,$ where $d$ must necessarily divide $N$ and $\gcd(a, d) = 1.$
The first multiplication gives $\dfrac {N!}{N^N},$ while the second yields $\displaystyle \prod_{d | N} \prod_{\substack{a \le d-1 \\ \gcd(a, d) = 1}} \frac ad = \prod_{d | N} \frac {\Pi(d)}{d^{\varphi(d)}},$ where $\Pi(N)$ denotes the sought product.
The result now follows from the Möbius inversion formula (in multiplicative notation): 
$\displaystyle \Pi(N) = N^{\varphi(N)} \prod_{d | N} \left( \frac {d!}{d^d} \right)^{\mu(d)}.$

For what it is worth, note that if $N$ is $2, 4,$ a power of an odd prime or twice the power of an odd prime, so that we may find a primitive root modulo $N,$ say $g,$ then the sought product is just $g^{\varphi(N)(\varphi(N)+1)/2}.$

Comment: Your remark regarding primitive roots should be made mod N.  Taking N=9 I get 2240 which is not the 21st power of any integer.  Also g^phi(N) will be 1, so the result will be a square root of 1 mod N.  Gerhard "I Like The Proof Idea" Paseman, 2012.05.20

Comment: ... which will be -1 mod N, in a manner akin to the proof of Wilson's theorem.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.20

Answer (score 2):

To get the asymptotic, one can replace the factorial in the exact formula by the Stirling formula. Then the desired quantity can be estimated as follows:
$$
c\cdot A_N\le (\dots)\le C\cdot A_N
$$
with
$$
A_N=N^{\phi(N)}\cdot \prod_{d|N}(\sqrt{2\pi d}\cdot e^{-d})^{\mu(N/d)}=(N/e)^{\phi(N)}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I will slightly expand upon my comment.  For $N$ a prime, one has the desired product being
$(N-1)!$.  For $N=pq$, a product of two primes, the desired product is $\frac{N! pq}{p!q^p q!p^q}$ .  I have not worked it out, but one should note a similarity between this representation and that of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_pq(x)$.  For square free $N=pqr\ldots$ I imagine an analogous relation holds.

**EDIT 2012.05.19** Thanks to Gjergji Zaimi, the above idea can be extended and nicely
expressed in terms of the Moebius function $\mu()$ and the Euler totient function $\phi()$
as
$$N^{\phi(N)}\prod_{d|N}\left(\frac{d!}{d^d}\right)^{\mu(N/d)} .$$
(I have faith enough to post it, but have not fully verified it myself.  It looks right to me.) 
**END EDIT 2012.05.19**

If you want something rougher but still in the ball park, consider $(N!)^2$ as product of terms of the form $(n+1-i)i$, which for many i look like $o(N^2)$.  Then the desired product is something like $\phi(N)/N$ fraction of those terms, perhaps with a power of e to take
care of the discrepancy.  So I nominate without proof $[(N!)^{1/N}/e]^{\phi(N)}$ as a rough estimate.  I imagine provable upper and lower bounds are a mere exponential factor away from this estimate.

Gerhard "Ask Me About Rough Estimates" Paseman, 2012.05.18

Comment: The expression is $$n^{\phi(n)}\prod_{d|n}\left(\frac{d!}{d^d}\right)^{\mu(n/d)}$$

Comment: Nice.  If you don't post it as a separate answer, I'll steal it (with attribution).  Gerhard "Or Beg Or Borrow Or..." Paseman, 2012.05.18

Comment: While this is a rather jumpy function, I am guessing there is a nice expression (or at least an asymptotic formula) for the product of all this for $N$ going from $1$ to $M$ (or if you take logs, the sum of logs)

Comment: @Gerhard: could you comment my own answer in light of yours.