# In ZF, are there infinite planar graphs that are not 4-colorable?

Tags: graph-theory

This is a follow-up to:
[Are infinite planar graphs still 4-colorable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151916/are-infinite-planar-graphs-still-4-colorable)

Specifically, absent the axiom of choice, is there an explicit example of an (probably uncountably) infinite planar graph that is not 4-colorable?

Comment: What's your definition of 'planarity'? I would expect that any reasonable definition here would lead to a well-ordering on the graph nodes...

Comment: I suspect that any answer may depend on the definition of planarity, and I will refrain from imposing any particular definition; I am just interested in any relevant example. Why would a well-ordering of nodes be particularly important?

Comment: A graph $(V, E)$ is called planar if there are maps $f: V\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $g$ from $E$ to the set of arcs in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the arc correspnding to an edge $(a,b)$ connects $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ . and no two  arcs $g(e)$, $g(e')$ intersect except at end points providef $e\ne e'$.  Is there a different definition?

Comment: @Mark One might want to consider rather than a global embedding only local ones.

Comment: To the OP, such a graph would indeed have to be uncountable: otherwise we could apply Konig's Lemma (fix an enumeration of the graph and build a tree whose nodes of height $n$ correspond to four-colorings of the first $n$ nodes of the graph, and conclude that that tree is infinite via the usual four-color theorem). Interestingly, I *don't* at the moment see how to rule out the possibility of an uncountable-but-well-orderable example!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry, that was a blindingly stupid moment on my part. Consider the graph with vertex set $\mathbb{R}\times\{1,2\}$ and edge relation given by $(a,b)E(c,d)$ iff $a=c$. I don't see how this wouldn't be considered planar, but $\mathbb{R}$ isn't well-orderable in ZF alone.

Comment: If AC is true then "locally planar" should imply "planar", But if it is not true then there should be a graph $G$ which is locally planar but not planar and then $G$ should not be 4-colorable, Right?

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's a very good example, although it also points to a plausible path towards resolving the question (one way or the other) : can one sensibly define connectedness on a planar graph, and can the question be reduced to the corresponding question for connected graphs?

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712013/can-there-exist-an-uncountable-planar-graph

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Connectedness for large graphs can be defined as usual (existence of finite paths between any two points), and we can still get large planar connected graphs: consider the graph with vertex set the unit circle + the origin, and an edge between the origin and each point on the circle but no other edges.