# Relatively primes spirals

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, discrete-geometry

When exploring the structure of points of the integer lattice
whose two coordinates are relatively prime
(call these *r-prime points*),<sup>1</sup>
I looked at spirals analogous to "Gaussian prime spirals."<sup>2</sup>
Start at an r-prime point $(a,b)$,
walk vertically (North) until you hit another r-prime point,
then walk West until another r-prime point is hit, then South, then East,
continuing to turn counterclockwise
$90^\circ$ at r-prime points until you re-encounter an earlier point,
approached from the same direction as last hit, and so fall
into a cycle.
(The start point is
considered approached from its left.)
Unlike the Gaussian prime spirals, these "relatively primes spirals"
are not generally visually interesting.
Many are just $4$-cycles, e.g.:
$$
(223, 2), (223, 3), (221, 3), (221, 2)
$$
Let me illustrate one more before asking a question.
Starting at $(495,2)$ leads to a cycle of length $44$:
$$
(495, 2), (495, 4), (493, 4), (493, 3), (494, 3), (494, 5), (493, 5),
(493, 4), (495, 4), (495, 7), (494, 7), (494, 5), (496, 5), (496, 7),
(495, 7), (495, 4), (497, 4), (497, 5), (496, 5), (496, 3), (497, 3),
(497, 4), (495, 4), (495, 2), (497, 2), (497, 3), (496, 3), (496, 1),
(497, 1), (497, 2), (495, 2), (495, 1), (496, 1), (496, 3), (494, 3),
(494, 1), (495, 1), (495, 2), (493, 2), (493, 1), (494, 1), (494, 3),
(493, 3), (493, 2)
$$
Here is an illustration of this cycle:

---

[image: (495,2)]

---

A natural question is:

> Does any start point lead to an infinite path that never cycles?

A candidate infinite path starts at $(5,2)$:
$$
(5, 2), (5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 1), (5, 1), (5, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3),
(2,3), (2,1), \ldots
$$
Here is its first $200$ turns:

---

[image: (5,2):200]

---

And here is its first $1000$ turns:

---

[image: (5,2):1000]

---

And here is its first $10000$ turns:

---

[image: (5,2):10000]

---

I've tracked it out to $10^6$ turns (reaching out to $(87652,87655)$), and still no cycle.
So, in addition to the general question above, a more specific question
is whether $(5,2)$ ever cycles.

*Added animation*:

---

[image: rprime200.gif]

---

---

<sup>1</sup>[Arbitrarily long composite anti-diagonals?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/257969/6094)

<sup>2</sup>[Gaussian prime spirals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91423/)

Comment: What happens when you run the process in reverse starting at $(5,2)$?

Comment: If this path doesn't run forever, it necessarily meets its own tail. My hope is that the tail makes it to negative numbers, and that we can show there is a wall separating negative and positive numbers with only one path through - a path that $(5,2)$ already used. This would show it runs forever.

Comment: The backwards direction is West, North, East, South.

Comment: Those interested in primes and spirals may want to check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072308/help-with-a-prime-number-spiral-which-turns-90-degrees-at-each-prime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First note that, in the path, the coordinates are always positive, because whenever any coordinate decreases to $1$ you hit a relatively prime point, turn, hit another relatively prime point, and then the coordinate starts increasing again,

Next consider the following set of posiitions and next directions:

A $(x,y), y>x+1$, any direction

B $(x,x+1)$, North, East, or West

C $(x,x-1)$, North

This set is closed under your operation. The reason is that if you ever leave type A you must be traveling South or East and hit the R-prime point $(x,x+1)$, so you are then traveling East or North, hence be in type B. If you leave type B and travel North or West you return to A, and traveling east you skip the non-R-prime point $(x+1,x+1)$ (note $x$ is at least $1$) and travel straight to $(x+2,x+1)$ and turn North, hence in a point in C. Finally C returns to B in the same way by skipping $(x,x)$ (note $x$ is at least $2$) and turning West.

Because your spiral enters this closed set, it never leaves it and hence never returns to its initial point. Because the flow is reversible, this means it must run forever without repeating.

Comment: This answer is at least as awesome as the question!

Comment: Beautiful argument! It appears (visually) that, not only doesn't the $(5,2)$ spiral close and repeat, but it also seems never to repeat the same "structural units" (however defined) as it walks out above the $y=x$ diagonal. If you also have any remarks on that behavior, I would appreciate your insights. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I'm not sure I see what you mean. In your "first 1,000 turns" picture, the same (small) structural unit appears near $(20,20)$ and near $(50,50)$. If the sequence were random, we would expect a structural unit of size $n$, whatever that means, to repeat after an exponential-in-$n$ number of steps. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke In lieu of that, two fun facts I think I can prove: 1. This sequence, when extended backwards in time, is symmetric about the $(x,y)$ axis 2. every other path is closed.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke 1. This is easy to check from the fact that the backwards evolution rule is the forwards evolution rule, flipped around the $x=y$ axis. 2. Check first for paths contained in the sets A, B, C. Observe that, in this set, the only way to get from $y= p-\epsilon$ to $y=p + \epsilon$ for a prime $p$ is by passing vertically through $(p,p)$ - everywhere else you will be stopped by a relatively prime point and turn around. The path starting at $(5,2)$ passes through $(p,p)$ because it is infinite, so no other path can. Then use this symmetry to handle paths in the other octant.

Comment: Yes, now I see the structural repeats, reflected across $y=-x$. "2. every other path is closed": This accords with my experiments.